# How use ArrayAdapter<T> with complex Layout?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

This is the first time I need to use the ArrayAdapter<T> to show a multi-item Row-Layout. After a lot of successful work with different adapters this one is driving me crazy.

getView(..., position, ...) always returns 0-7[EDIT] so I never see elements in my ArrayList that are on position >= 7[/EDIT]. I know, this is the visible position, but how do I select the correct object in the ArrayList?

EDIT: Currently I only get the first 8 elements out of my array because position only comes in from 0-7 - even on a 50 element ArrayList. I don't see a way to position within the ArrayList without a "real" position.

The docs say the following - but I don't get it. Did somebody successfully implement an ArrayAdapter<T> with a complex layout? What do the doc mean and how should I implement it?

> If you want to use a more complex
>   layout, use the constructors that also
>   takes a field id. That field id should
>   reference a TextView in the larger
>   layout resource. However the TextView
>   is referenced, it will be filled with
>   the toString() of each object in the
>   array. You can add lists or arrays of
>   custom objects. Override the
>   toString() method of your objects to
>   determine what text will be displayed
>   for the item in the list. To use
>   something other than TextViews for the
>   array display, for instance,
>   ImageViews, or to have some of data
>   besides toString() results fill the
>   views, override getView(int, View,
>   ViewGroup) to return the type of view
>   you want.

Many thanks in advance

hjw

Here's the code so far:

```
public class HappyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Happy> {

  static class ViewHolder {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView  textViewBottom;
    private TextView  textViewTop;
  }

  private ArrayList<Happy> arrayListHappy;
  private DrawableCache    drawableCache = DrawableCache.getInstance();
  private int              layout;

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return arrayListHappy.size();
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View contentView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    // position always 0-7

    View       view = null;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    if (contentView == null) {
      LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      view = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, null);

      if (view != null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.happyactivity_row_image_left);
        viewHolder.textViewBottom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.happyactivity_row_text_bottom);
        viewHolder.textViewTop = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.happyactivity_row_text_top);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
      }
    } else {
      view = contentView;
      viewHolder = (ViewHolder) contentView.getTag();
    }

    if (viewHolder != null) {
      Happy happy = arrayListHappy.get(position);
      if (happy != null) {
        viewHolder.imageView.setUrl(happy.getImageThumbnail());
        drawableCache.fetchDrawable(happy.getImageThumbnail(), viewHolder.imageView);
        viewHolder.textViewBottom.setText(String.valueOf(position));
        viewHolder.textViewTop.setText(String.valueOf(viewHolder.position));
      }
    }

    return view;
  }

  public HappyAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Happy> arrayListHappy) {
    super(context, layout, arrayListHappy);

    this.arrayListHappy = arrayListHappy;
    this.layout = layout;
  }
}
```

This is part of the Row-Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/happyactivity_row_image_left"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

  <TextView
    style="@style/TextViewStandard"
    android:id="@+id/happyactivity_row_text_top"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

  <TextView
    style="@style/TextViewStandard"
    android:id="@+id/happyactivity_row_text_bottom"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I only see elements 0-7 from my ArrayList even if it's bigger. I did EDIT that part in my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't add comments yet so have to answer. As others have noted it isn't really clear what's not working. However, you are only seeing positions 0-7 being inflated as this is the only portion of the list that is currently visible, as you noted yourself. Other rows (with higher position numbers) won't be inflated until you scroll down the list.

Although it uses the BaseAdapter class, rather than ArrayAdapter that you are using, you could look at List14.java in the ApiDemos sample code (ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.java) as the principle is the same. When using ArrayAdapter though, you don't need to override all the methods that this sample code does (just getView).

Comment: When scrolling down position stays at 0-7 - even if ArrayList is bigger.

Comment: It's working now. Thanks. I don't know what I did. Seems that one of the changes throughout the day was to store position in ViewHolder and use happyAdapter.get(viewHolder.position) instead of happyAdapter.get(position)